# CiviCase activities: cursor jumps in wrong order

Tags: civicase, activities

Iam adding a new activity within a case, filling out only the fields
A) subject
B) details.

Then going to change the status and clicking in, the cursor jumps back to subject.
If i change the flow, clicking in the akkordion "follow up" or others, the behaviour is as it should be, the cursor does not jump back to top.

Tried in different civicrm's 5.28.3. Anyone who can confirm that? I guess its coming with one of the latest update (at least 5.21.x or earlier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can turn off popups at Administer - Customize - Display Preferences, near the bottom there's a checkbox "Enable popup forms". The cursor doesn't jump then.